# Rails - Allowing for calling in Model Validation in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my user.rb model:

```
INVALID_EMAILS = %w(gmail.com hotmail.com)
validates_format_of :email, :without => /#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/, :message => "That email domain won't do.", :on => :create
```

For various reasons, I want to be able to use this logic in my controller to check an email's input before it is user.created, which is when the above normall runs.

How can I turn the above into a method that I can call in controllers other than user? Possible?

And if is called and returned false I then want to do errors.add so I can let the user know why?

Thanks

**Trying:**

```
  def validate_email_domain(emailAddy)
    INVALID_EMAILS = %w(gmail.com googlemail.com yahoo.com ymail.com rocketmail.com hotmail.com facebook.com)
    reg = Regexp.new '/#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/'
    self.errors.add('rox', 'Hey, Ruby rox. You have to say it !') unless reg.match attribute
  end
```

**Update:**

```
..
  Rails.logger.info validate_email_domain(email)
...

  def valid_email_domain(emailAddy)
    reg = Regexp.new '/#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/'
    return true if emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a constant inside a method, because that would make it "dynamic constant assignment". Instead, define this constant in your model class and then reference it in your controller by using `User::INVALID_EMAILS`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I didn't know that. I updated it to: protected
  def validate_email_domain(emailAddy)
    reg = Regexp.new '/#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join('|')}/'
    self.errors.add('rox', 'Hey, stop!') unless reg.match attribute
  end
but now I get the error: "NoMethodError (undefined method `|' for "/\#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join(":String):"

Comment: What about something like this:   def valid_email_domain(emailAddy)
    reg = Regexp.new '/#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/'
    return true if emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0
  end

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I understand you.

You want to do something like below:

```
u = User.new
u.email = "jsmith@gmail.com"
if !u.valid?
  puts u.errors.to_xml 
  //do something
  return
end
```

What you do with those errors is going to come down to how you want those reported back, usually I just shoot them back as xml into a flash[:error], which is the normal default behavior if you're doing scaffolds. The puts is there so you can see how to access the errors.

**Additional**

As a rule try to avoid duplicating validation logic. Rails provides everything you need for validating without creating different methods in different places to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: thanks but I can't do that in my case as I the other user validations will cause issues. I just want to valid the email

Comment: I used this method, then in my User model, I have an errors hash of various validations that failed. I just check for user.errors[:email].